# How to get the javascript beacon information in server side?

Tags: javascript, beacon

In client side I send data using beacon to a server. How do I get that information in the server side. Please Help Me!

Comment: _“Please Help Me!”_ - please make that possible in the first place. [ask]

Comment: Okay.. But anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries.. I found the answer. The data sent by beacon is in the body of the request.. So we can retrieve the data by request.getReader().